# How to set file modification time via ftp with python

Tags: python-2.7, ftp

How to change a modification time of file via ftp?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/specs/draft-somers-ftp-mfxx-04.txt), the command is MFMT:

The syntax of the MFMT command is:

> mfmt = "MFMT" SP time-val SP pathname CRLF
>
> As with all FTP commands, the "MFMT" command label is interpreted
>   in    a case insensitive manner.
>
> The "time-val" specifies the last modification time to be applied
>   to    the object.
>
> The "pathname" specifies an object in the NVFS.
>
> The server-PI MUST respond to the MFMT command with a 213 reply, or
>   an error response if the object does not exist, the last modification 
>   time could not be modified, or some other error has occurred.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330786/preserve-image-created-date-when-uploading-to-ftp) has more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible

"The original FTP specification and recent extensions to it do not include any way to preserve the time and data for files uploaded to a FTP server."