# Preserving file modified timestamp if using ftp_put to upload to remote server

Tags: php, ftp, put

I have a php script that uploads files from one folder, to a remote ftp server. 
It works fine uploading the files to the remote server. Connection is fine.

However, the file modified timestamps of the uploaded files are always the time when they are transferred to the remote server. Is there any way to preserve the time modified when I use ftp_put to upload to the remote server? Or do I need a different approach?

Below is the code. The connection is fine, and ftp_put does its job.

```
foreach (glob("$path/Content/*.*") as $filename) {
    $contentupstate = ftp_put($connection, "Content/". basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY); 
};
```

Just wanted to check if this was possible, or if we have to do something on the remote server.
Thanks for anyone that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to AbraCadaver for the tip. After some testing and more research, here is the code that worked for me. I had to do it after the `ftp_put`, and then use `MFMT` instead of `MDTM` because the `MDTM` syntax wasn't working for me. It works and thanks to everyone.

```
foreach (glob("$path/Content/*.*") as $filename) {
    $time = date('YmdGis', filemtime($filename));
    $contentupstate = ftp_put($connection, "Content/". basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY); 
    $filemodstate = ftp_raw($connection, "MFMT " . $time . " Content/". basename($filename)); 
};
```

Comment: `MDTM` is for retrieving file timestamp. Only some FTP servers support a non-standard syntax with two arguments to set the timestamp too. See [Preserve image created date when uploading to FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36330786/850848).

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities I think, if the FTP server supports them (not tested).  First get the modification time in the proper format:

```
$time = date('YmdGis', file_mtime($filename));
```

Before the PUT (I think):

```
$stat = ftp_raw($connection, "MDTM $time Content/". basename($filename));
```

Or after the PUT:

```
$stat = ftp_raw($connection, "SITE UTIME $time $time $time Content/". basename($filename));
```

Comment: Either way, it has to be **after** the "PUT" – You cannot set a timestamp of a file that does not exist yet. And even if it has existed already, the "PUT" would overwrite the timestamp with the current time.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I couldn't find good examples of MDTM, but the one I did see it looked to be a command telling the server this before the PUT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try out and get back to you on the results. Thanks!